# In the phrase "...redirecting your focus on to what is working..." Why ON TO and not only TO?

Tags: prepositions, difference, usage, prepositional-verbs

In the phrase:

> ...redirecting your focus on to what is working...

Why "on to" and not only "to"?

At first when I saw that phrase I thought the preposition **ON** was related to the verb **focus**, but at a second and third analyses I sort of notice that **focus** is not being used as a verb, but as a noun, so that explanation doesn't apply.

I thought then that maybe **ON** was related to the verb **redirecting** but couldn't find any instances when this preposition is used with that verb.

So my question remains, why **focus ON TO**, when only TO would have conveyed the same meaning?

Comment: Is that text from a transcription of speech? It is just  **focus on** and **redirect someone to** some other matter. In fact, if the focus is a physical object, it's fine. If it's an abstract, it's OK but not necessary. So, it is grammatical, in fact.

Comment: It is a transcription of a speech. But isnt't focus on a phrasal verb? And it is not the verb of the sentence so I still don't understand why use ON. Is it to give emphasis?

Answer (score 1):

Speech is not always uniform or perfect or perfectly grammatical as one might expect it to be.

One phenomenon that occurs is switching horses in mid-stream (in the middle of a sentence)

- Let's **redirect our focus to** the second list of issues.
- Let's **redirect our focus from or on viruses to** bacteria.

Yes, **one focuses on something.** But that does  not make focus followed by on into a phrasal verb.

- What did you **focus on** at the meeting? means:
- We **focused on various subjects**. on various subjects is a prepositional phrase.

So, no, it is not a phrasal verb per se. He focused the camera on the model. Thus: He focused on her. It is usually a prepositional phrase.and sometimes the phrase disappears: What did you focus on [at the meeting]? has this meaning = On what subject did you focus? Anyway, in speaking, I can see why a speaker might say "redirect your focus on to what is working". **This is a typical phenomenon in spoken language.**

A speaker might very well link *to focus on* [some subject] with **redirect focus to something**. It is not a mistake per se. **In writing, it would probably be edited to *to* or *on*.**

Comment: (I realize this is two yrs old) In your second bullet point, "Let's **redirect our focus from or on viruses to** bacteria," I think some of that is meant to be an optional substitute, but it's not clear to me which part? I guess "... from [or on] viruses..." Btw, I suspect that the usage in the original question is actually thinking of "onto" (in which case, technically, it really ought to spell it that way...)

Comment: @AndyBonner OR means: **redirect our focus from viruses to bacteria** OR **redirect our focus on viruses to bacteria**.  "onto" would not be right here.

Comment: I thought that was what you meant. And agreed, "onto" is inappropriate, but I suspect it was what the original quote was going for (e.g. "direct your flashlight's beam onto this wall"), and they compounded the error by substituting "on to" for "onto."

Comment: @AndyBonner I don't think the original quote had anything to do with an idea involving something physical like "onto the wall".